# When devirtualization can be assumed as simple for compiler to be done?

Tags: c++, inheritance, compiler-optimization

I would like to be able to inject dependencies to my classes for testing purposes.

The simplest way to achieve that is prepare abstract class (interface) A and write AClass and AMock inheriting in both from A. Now I am able to test B class by injecting AMock when it compiles in Test configuration or injecting AClass in Release and Debug configuration.

I use inheritance only to test my code so I don't want to pay in space and time complexity at runtime in Release and Debug.

So the questions are:

If in code only AClass inherit from abstract interface A it is easy to remove effort of inheritance for compiler?

In which most popular compilers I can expect this type of optimization?

How can I test that optimization happen?

Comment: Couldn't you just compile the code in Test configuration with mock implementation of A, and Release/Debug with the actual implementation, without any interfaces? Or do you need also the actual A class to be in the testing?

Comment: For GCC, please see: http://hubicka.blogspot.com.es/search/label/devirtualization, it's probably the best guide about devirtualization. Basically, if you use LTO, you may be able to achieve devirtualization.

Comment: If you really care you might consider using CRTP for static polymorphism instead.

Comment: Ok, my question was theoretical, so I can't answer to Sami, but your idea sounds good. If I wouldn't be able to totally separate compilation, there also is info from Javier and sharptooth. Thank you :)